# when to use spring boot test and when to use Mockito?

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-test

when to use spring boot test whe to use Mockito? which one is suitable for unit test and which one for integration test?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an either-or question. You need and use both for writing unit and integration tests with Spring Boot.

When writing unit tests to verify, e.g. a business logic in isolation, you can solely rely on JUnit and Mockito.

Depending on how you define the word *unit*, you might also include tests that use Spring Boot Test slice annotations (e.g. `@WebMvcTest`) as unit tests. In such cases, you also work with Mockito as you mock other collaborators with `@MockBean` (annotation from Spring Boot, which creates a Mockito mock).

It might make sense to start with this [overview of testing Spring Boot applications](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-unit-and-integration-testing-overview/).